# Include HTML files with a PHP script in a different directory while keeping file paths in HTML intact?

Tags: php, html, filepath

From a PHP script, I want to include a "header.php" and "footer.php" file, which are in a different directory. They have HTML in them, and the HTML has references to file paths in them such as:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
```

and

```
<a href="about.php">About Us</a>
```

When I include this html from the php file (which is in another directory) the html looks for the file paths in the directory it's included *into*, instead of where it's included *from*.

Is there an easy fix to that? I realize I could go through the html and prepend something like `<?php echo dirname(__FILE__); ?>` into every file path. But is that the correct way to do that?

Should I restructure my files completely?

Currently the reason the php script is in a different directory is because currently most of my web pages are in the root directory of the server -- so my css js and template files are in folders named "css" "js" and "inc"; but I want to have some web pages be in a url of the format "[root]/Account/settings.php". So I'm trying to put some php pages into a folder in the root directory named Account. But when I try to include my templating files, the file paths in them get messed up.

Comment: URLs in the HTML are processed by the browser, not the server. It interprets them relative to the URL of the document that contains them, since it doesn't know anything about the including that took place on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following path -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/custom.css">
```

and

```
<a href="/about.php">About Us</a>
```

This is assuming that the CSS directory and About Us are both in your document root. Really a simple HTML and path issue rather than PHP, if I am understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you! Does this work for php include file paths too? If not, what can I use to do the same thing in that case?

Comment: Try `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/includes/script.php');` - I do this often. Also suggest you look into an MVC framework such as Laravel or CodeIgniter.